# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I am calling a post API, in which I have to send FormData but after receiving the response when I try to parse that response I am getting below exception.

```
static Future<String> versionApiRequest(String storeId, String deviceId) async {
    String versionApi = 'https://xxxxxxx/${storeId}/api_v5/version';
    print('$versionApi , $storeId');

    FormData formData = new FormData.from(
        {"device_id": deviceId, "device_token":"", "platform":"android"});
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    Response response = await dio.post(versionApi, data: formData,
        options: new Options(
        contentType: ContentType.parse("application/json")));
    print(response.data.toString());

    StoreData storeData = storeDataFromJson(response.data);
    //print("-------store.success ---${storeData.success}");
    return "";
  }
```

i am getting below error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
    #0      ApiController.versionApiRequest (package:restroapp/src/networkhandler/ApiController.dart:43:54)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

below is my Model class
https://gist.github.com/achinverma/641774f50d27b2f4f5be9f1c341f0fc2

Comment: As you know that the response is in `map` for it can not be directly converted to string as you wrote this `print(response.data.toString());`
Try to map it in object first and then print that object.

Comment: ok, let me try this fix

Comment: White printing object, put `toJson();`

Comment: @SharadPaghadal, i got Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2) after doing response.data.toString()

Comment: instead of managing class json method at your own, you can use this - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries

Comment: i am using dio: 2.1.13  lib to send formData in API, but my json is validated in json lint, i don't know why i am getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197809/discussion-between-achin-and-sharad-paghadal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this for mapping response to your model class

`var responseData = StoreData.fromJson(response.data);`